# Do QString's toUpper()/toLower() member functions only convert Latin alpha characters?

Tags: qt, unicode, posix

According to the documentation QString's toUpper() and toLower() member functions convert in the C-locale. Does it mean that only Posix Portable Character Set characters (Latin A-Z/a-z) are converted and any international unicode characters are left as-is?

Answer (score 2):

We can easily test this with the simple test program here:

```
#include <QString>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    QString s("БΣTest3φب");

    std::cout << "String: " << s.toStdString() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Lower: " << s.toLower().toStdString() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Upper: " << s.toUpper().toStdString() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Which returns:

```
09:48:48: Starting /home/tzig/test/test ...
String: БΣTest3φب
Lower: бσtest3φب
Upper: БΣTEST3Φب
09:48:49: /home/tzig/test/test exited with code 0
```

So we know that:

- Cyrillic letters work fine
- Latin letters work fine
- Numbers are untouched
- Greek letters work fine
- Arabic letters don't have uppercase/lowercase so they are untouched

Feel free to test other Unicode characters with the test program.

Comment: Interesting, so what does this mean that these functions convert in C-locale?

Comment: I suppose what documentation means is that the conversion happens in the currently set C-locale, not necessarily in the POSIX/C locale unless that is what the C-locale is actually set to. I did, however, tried setlocale(LC_ALL, "C"); prior to calling toLower() and it still worked for non-ASCII characters on Windows.